# php html unwanted spaces because of using "\n" line breaks

Tags: php, html, line-breaks

look at this:

```
<?php
    echo "<p>this is my <a href='#'>\nlink1\n</a>\n, <a href='#'>\nlink2\n</a>\n, <a href='#'>\nlink3\n</a>\n and <a href='#'>\nlink4\n</a>\n!</p>\n";
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
this is my link1 , link2 , link3 and link4 !
```

INSTEAD OF:

```
this is my link1, link2, link3 and link4!
```

WHY IS THIS?

there are unwanted spaces between "link1" and "," or "link4" and "!".
and also interesting is the fact that if there is a space after the "\n" .. it works.

this really disturbs my work (and workflow).

How to avoid this bug/mistake?

Comment: Quit randomly inserting `\n`s?  :P

Comment: it's not "randomly". "randomly" does not solve this problem!

Comment: Unless you're planning on outputting this HTML in a human-readable way, those newlines serve no purpose but adding extra characters for users to download. All competent browsers will automatically format the HTML in a human-readable way for debugging. So what exactly do you need them for?

Comment: wether they're needed or not … why does it behave like this? the question is not why i need to output those line-breaks. the question is why they are converted to spaces IF i do want to output them?

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith: Because [that's how HTML works](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1).  Whitespace, when it appears between inline elements and text, is typically rendered as a single space char.  Whether and which spaces are still visible, is rather implementation-dependent.  Not seeing where HTML 5 even tries to specify what happens, but if it does, it'll be similar to HTML 4 in that regard.

Comment: ok. thx. i'm using html5. so yes. same here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The observed behaviour is not a bug; it is exacty as defined in the HTML standard.

When your browser sees a newline, it is interpeted as a whitespace. (whitespace is visualized as a space character).
if your browser sees multiple (consecutive) whitespaces, it only will display a single space.

If you do not want spaces to be displayed for newlines, remove the newlines before `echo`-ing the string to the browser:

```
echo str_replace("\n", '', "<p>this is my <a href='#'>\nlink1\n</a>\n, (...)");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    echo "<p>this is my <a href='#'>link1</a>,\n<a href='#'>link2</a>,\n<a href='#'>link3</a> and \n<a href='#'>link4</a>!</p>";
?>
```

that should fix it.
Just leave the "\n" out. It is a newline and browsers 'convert' that to a space.

A `\n` is a newline in the code. If you want newlines outputted in your browser. just use `<br/>` instead of `\n`

Comment: why are they necessary, can't find that in your question?

Comment: It *is* the solution, @JohnDoeSmith.  If you have a `\n` it will be converted to a space when the browser renders it.  You may not like it, but that's the reality.